# Deploy Bottle Application on Nginx

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, bottle

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server setup that currently runs a Ruby on Rails application on a Passenger / Nginx install.  I decided to play around with some Python and wrote a small application using [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).  I would like to deploy this application to my server.
I followed [this guide](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/python-uwsgi/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin) on setting up my server to run Python applications.  When I run `sudo service uwsgi restart` I get the following error message:

```
Restarting app server(s) uwsgi                                     
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from  
/usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini [uWSGI] parsing config file /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/example.net.xml  
open("./python_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.cline 4700]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python_plugin.so: cannot  open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!   
Sat Dec  8 18:29:14 2012 - [WARNING] option "app" is deprecated: use the more advanced "mount" option
```

I really don't know a ton about Python, I have installed the plugins I need via `easy_install`

Which are:

- pymongo
- beautifulsoup
- bottle

My question is: how do I deploy this simple application to my server?
Thank you

Comment: can you verify that `python_plugin.so` is present in `/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python` and that access right are appropriate?

Comment: As a general rule, install modules with `pip` instead of `easy_install` whenever possible- trust me, it will save you pain in the future.

Comment: @Raber When I do a listing it's present  

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 142936 Jul 17 02:28 python27_plugin.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37 Dec 10 16:39 python_plugin.so -> /etc/alternatives/uwsgi-plugin-python
`

Comment: I tried reinstalling uwsgi via `pip` and I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that Passenger will run WSGI apps.  I followed the instructions on this post http://kbeezie.com/using-python-nginx-passenger/ and had no trouble getting it working.

It was actually pretty easy in the end.

Here is my adaptor in case anybody else has trouble:

https://github.com/nick-desteffen/astronomy-pics/blob/master/passenger_wsgi.py